# Ajuda com deslocamento de bits em C++

Tags: c++

Bom, em um exercício de programação foi me dado o seguinte programa, e perguntava qual é sua saída

```
 using namespace std; 

 union U1 {    
    union U2{     
      unsigned a: 3;   
      unsigned b: 4;   
      unsigned c: 1;    
    }u2;    
    int d;    
    void Exibe(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned, int); 
}u1; 

int main(){    
   u1.u2.a=2;    
   u1.u2.a<<=1;    
   u1.u2.b=16;     
   u1.u2.b-=4;    
   u1.u2.c=(u1.u2.b)>>3;    
   u1.d=17; 
   cout << u1.u2.a << "   " << u1.u2.b << "   " << u1.u2.c << "   " << u1.d << endl; 
}
```

Após a execução do código a saída é '1 1 1 17' , minha dúvida está no porquê dessa saída, pesquisei sobre deslocamento de bits e juntando com o pouco que foi dado em aula ainda não consegui entender, poderiam me ajudar a entender?

Comment: Você executou o código? Se sim, ao menos tem a saída. Perguntar sobre o significado/razão da saída é outra coisa bem diferente, aí sim mais válida. Desculpe comentar, mas do jeito que a pergunta está parece exercício de programação + preguiça de digitar e compilar. Vc é bem vindo aqui, mas observe que este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour].

Comment: Sim, eu executei, a saída é '1   1   1   17' , é que eu não entendi mesmo qual é a lógica dessa saída, pesquisei sobre deslocamento de bits mas ainda assim estou perdido. E sim, é uma questão de um exercício de programação onde todas as questões são mais ou menos nesse contexto, pedi ajuda nessa para entender como fazer.

Comment: Ok. Então edite a pergunta, e adicione nela essas informações que me passou. Aí eu voto para reabrir. ;)

Answer (score 0):

O deslocamento de bits move os bits para a direita ou para a esquerda e acaba significando uma multiplicação ou divisão por 2 do valor que lá estava, mas é um pouco mais complicado que isso.

Para ajudar, vamos seguir seu programa linha por linha, mostrando os valores binários:

```
int main(){    
   u1.u2.a=2;    
   u1.u2.a<<=1;    
   u1.u2.b=16;     
   u1.u2.b-=4;    
   u1.u2.c=(u1.u2.b)>>3;    
   u1.d=17; 
   cout << u1.u2.a << "   " << u1.u2.b << "   " << u1.u2.c << "   " << u1.d << endl; 
}
```

1) A variável u1.u2.a no seu caso, é iniciada com o valor 2 e tem 3 bits.

```
a = 010
```

2) A variável então é deslocada um bit para a esquerda.

```
a = 100 (que é a mesma coisa que multiplicar por 2) e o valor vira 4
```

3) A variável b é iniciada com 16 e tem 4 bits. O que significa que o valor inserido passa do valor aceito por ela... Então isso já começa a desandar o entendimento do que está acontecendo (note que isso é um bug e não deveria ser feito).

```
16 = 10000 
b = 0
```

4) Subtraindo 4 de b, deixaria o valor negativo, mas ele é unsigned, então você tem outro problema aqui, mas os bits seriam alterados.

```
b = 1100
```

5) Então é feito o deslocamento dos bits de b para atribuir em c. 3 bits para a direita.

```
b>>3 = 1
c = 1
```

6) Então ao atribuir 17 em d, tudo o que foi feito é apagado.

```
17 = 10001
```

Porém, como a U2 é uma union, ao fazer isso, você está alterando também a, b e c:

```
a = 001 (três bits de 17)
b = 0001 (quatro bits de 17)
c = 1 (um bit de 17)
d = 17 (ele continua sendo um inteiro)
```